# Java Multidimensional String giving a strange output

Tags: java

So I'm just playing around with a 2-D String array here and wanted to see how my output varies if I just print out only the row dimension of my actual array. Following is my code with the strange output.

```
public class TwoDimensionalArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] words = { { "Hello", "Mr.", "Spencer!" }, { "How", "Are", "You", "Doing", "Today?" },
                { "I", "recommend", "an", "outdoor", "activity", "for", "this", "evening." }

        };
for (int m = 0; m < words.length; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < words[m].length; n++) {
                System.out.println(words[m]);
            }
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922
[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922
[Ljava.lang.String;@7852e922
[Ljava.lang.String;@4e25154f
[Ljava.lang.String;@4e25154f
```

Comment: Java is printing out string array references.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing here, as pointed out by @yters, are references to the array.

Keep in mind that inside each array, you have another array now (because it is a two-dimensional array). So the result in your case of `words[0]` would be `["Hello","Mr.","Spencer!"]`.

When you perform a print statement in Java, you are relying on the objects `toString()` method to give you the correct information. In this case, the object you are doing this for is of type `String[]`, thus an Array. When running `toString()` on an Array, you will get the object reference printed out, which is the result you are getting. (e.g: `[Ljava.lang.String;@135fbaa4`
).

What you could do to print the array is write code like this:

```
    for (int m = 0; m < words.length; m++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words[m]));
    }
```

By using the Arrays util class, you can print each array inside your two dimensional array like that.

Comment: He already had the two loops done so using `words[m][n]` was ok too ;)

Comment: @AxelH yeah but the OP said this: `if I just print out only the row dimension`. So in my interpretation, he wanted to have the complete array for each index of m, without iterating over the index n as well. He also did not use N so I assumed as well that he did not really understand what he was doing. 

But of course, your point is valid, just a difference of interpretation of the question I suppose :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can change the line `System.out.println(words[m]);` to `System.out.println(words[m][n]);`